# Пропадает карта Yandex map (при скрытии/показе)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Использую компоненты Bootstrap. Имеется Tab, у которого есть вкладки. В одной из вкладок, находится карта Yandex Map. Проблема заключается в том, что при масштабировании страницы, либо после переключения вкладок, она в разметке остается (все фоновые операции по ней выполняются), а визуально не отображается. И чтобы ее отобразить вновь, необходимо делать манипуляции с масштабированием страницы.

```
var myMapDev;
function InitMapDevice() {
    myMapDev = new ymaps.Map('MapDevice', {        
        center: [1, 1],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: []
     },
        {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });                
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
InitMapDevice();
});

$('#ControlMenu > li > a').click(function () {        
        var CurrHrT = $(this).attr('href');

        if (CurrHrT == '#Map') {
            $('#LeftMenu').css('display','none');
            $('#Map').css('display', 'block'); //В этом элементе DIV находится карта <div id="MapDevice"></div>
        }
        else {
            $('#LeftMenu').css('display', 'block');
            $('#Map').css('display', 'none');
        }            
    });
```

Comment: Если вы предоставите минимальный воспроизводимый пример, то на вопрос будет проще ответить.

Comment: Можно пример ссылкой на jsfiddle, либо соберите его тут, так чтобы можно было посмотреть на результат выполнения вашего кода, а не на сам код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было принято следующее, при переключении таба или при появлении того или иного контейнера, вызывать следующую функцию:

```
function ResizeMapFit() {    
   myMapDev.container.fitToViewport();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема (скорее ограничение со стороны Яндекса по определенным соображениям).

Решается **ре-инициализацией** карты при каждом показе tab-a. Тем самым, вы можете де-инициализировать при скрытии и обратно инициализировать при активации вкладки.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, - т.е. map.destroy() вызывать?

Comment: Да, можете включить все в какую-то функцию, чтобы проверяло, если запущено > destroy > далее сново инициализировало.